# Angular 2 RC4 to latest - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" when extending

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had an older Angular 2 RC4 project I've updated to the latest version (now 2.0.0). I don't get any compilation errors when running `ng build` using the latest version (1.0.0-beta.14) of angular CLI, but when running `ng serve` I get the error in the title.

The base service in question looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


export class PkServiceBaseService {
  // Implementation
}
```

While the class extending the base service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


import { PkServiceBaseService } from "./";
import { JwtAuthorizationService } from "./";
import { Task } from "../shared";

@Injectable()
export class TaskService extends PkServiceBaseService {
  // Implementation
}
```

Both files are in the same directory, and exported through the `index.ts` file.

The strange thing is I was getting this same error in some model classes when using inheritance, but now that's disappeared.

Also, the stack trace for the error contains a reference to another service `UserService` that also extends `PkServiceBaseService`, but isn't used at all within `TaskService`.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information. I've omitted the implementation details as the issue seems to only be related to the inheritance, but I can certainly provide more information.

Full stack trace for reference:

```
__extends              @   task.service.ts:40
(anonymous function)   @   user.service.ts:11
(anonymous function)   @   user.service.ts:105
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
(anonymous function)   @   main.bundle.js:4803
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
(anonymous function)   @   prep-kids.component.ts:18
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
(anonymous function)   @   icon-registry.js:375
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
(anonymous function)   @   src async:7
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
(anonymous function)   @   main.bundle.js:81928
__webpack_require__    @   bootstrap 32723c5…:52
webpackJsonpCallback   @   bootstrap 32723c5…:23
(anonymous function)   @   main.bundle.js:1
```

**Edit:**
I should add that I've followed [the RC4 to RC5 migration steps](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) for Angular 2, as well as the [Upgrading from Beta.10 to Beta.14](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14) steps for Angular CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging and a fudging, I was finally able to get my app working again.

[This issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831) in the Angular CLI queue got me on the right track. It seems sometimes using wildcards in your `index.ts` file can cause issues finding that class after compilation.

For instance, before I was doing something like:

```
export * from "./user.service";
export * from "./pk-base-service.service";
```

But changing things in my `index.ts` to:

```
export {UserService} from "./user.service";
export {PkBaseService} from "./pk-base-service.service";
```

got rid of my problems.

There were also a few instances where I would get this same error from my model classes. Previously, when I had to models in the same folder I was able to do:

```
import { User } from "./";
```

Changing the import to:

```
import { User } from "./user.model";
```

Got rid of the error.

Answer (score 2):

It happened the same to me. In the end there were some circular dependencies in my code that system didn't complain about and webpack threw misleading messages.

In my case I have a shared module and a core module. Instead of importing shared I broke it to shared/menu, shared/icon and so on.

This broke all weird dependencies and started working quite fine

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue too, circular dependency of a component extending something defined in a service it was importing.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the order in the index.ts that was important.
Put my base class first and then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the -

```
export * from 'path/base-class-name';
```

from the `index.ts` and imported it into my base module.

```
import { BaseClass } from 'path/base-class-name';
```

This solved my issue.